# word after the space NSlog

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nslog

I am new bie to xcode may be question is silly but I am lagging with my home work. In a file I want to read a specific character after the string.

I want to read all the character after the space.

ex:

asasasasasas
  wewewewewewe
  qwqwqwqwqwqw
xyz_ 22 aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd
fgfgfgfgfgfgfg
ererererererer

abc_ 12 bbbbbbbbbb dddddddd
jkjkjkjkjkjkjk
lalallalalalal

---

everything is fine .. but i want to print after "xyz_ 22" as aaaaaaa
then 
bbbb
ccc

Comment: Means you want to show what is nsarray contain currently.

Comment: Look at the documentation for NSArray and  `componentsSeparatedByString`

Comment: You seem to have just blindly copied some code from an answer to your other question without taking the time to work out what it is doing and how it is working. READ THE DOCUMENTATION. It's there for a reason

Comment: to ur answer its easy 
NSArray*dd=[contentfile componentsSeperatedByString:@" "];
NSLog (@"%d",dd);
..................


but mine is a big file ex:
 asasasasasas          
  wewewewewewe        
  qwqwqwqwqwqw
xyz_ 22 aaaaaaaaaaa asasas bababab cacacac        
fgfgfgfgfgfgfg        
ererererererer

abc_ 12 bbbbbbbbbb       
jkjkjkjkjkjkjk     
lalallalalalal

after abc_12 i want to read "aaaaaaaa" then "asasasa" then "babababa"

Comment: using  whiteSpace :[contentfile componentsSeperatedByString:@" "];

Answer (score 1):

I think you seperate your string by  whiteSpace

```
NSArray*dd=[contentfile componentsSeperatedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it just be:

```
NSArray*dd=[contentfile componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Then you have an array of all the strings.